# Symmetry of convergence around a of a Taylor Polynomial

Tags: taylor-expansion

I heard the lecturer mention this shortly, so I'd like a more detailed explanation of it. He showed us a taylor approx. of ln(x) at x = 1, and showed that it only matches in the interval ]0,2], so symmetric around x = 1 with a radius of one...

But he didn't say more than that. Why is above the case? Has it something to do with ln(0) not being defined?

Comment: Great question. Yes, an interval of convergence is always symmetric around the point of expansion (except possibly at the endpoints of the interval as in your case). I'll let someone else give a full answer, but (1) yes, it does have to do with the singularity of $\ln x$ at zero, and (2) in a sense there's more to it than that. For example, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ based at $x = 0$ is $1$, despite that that function is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. (Hint: It has singularities at $\pm i$ in the complex plane, where *are* $1$ unit from $x = 0$.)